# ¿Como crear tablas dinámicas usando C# desde Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

> Necesito exactamente lo que pido, **mediante c#crear** una **tabla dinámica** en EXCEL con el formato que lo haría este, siendo **lo más similar** posible.

Este programa es parte de un desarrollo más grande, he cogido **tan solo la parte del código que hace referencia a esto** y he puesto abajo del todo una **tabla de datos generada por mí**, son lo necesario para poder recrear el ejemplo que tengo.

Me siento muy perdido y por eso pregunto aquí, tras haber intentado varias cosas durante días.

A parte de crear la tabla hay que pasar los datos de SQL a Excel, pero esa parte no supone gran complicación así que no creo necesario ponerla, ya que es un paso previo para conseguir lo que reflejo abajo.

Los pocos avances que tengo estan en el código de abajo, pero sigue sin funcionar nada.

***((Con los datos aquí puestos debería de haber un ejemplo completo mínimo y verificable del que se puedan hacer cosas.))***

Esto es lo que tengo por ahora:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace emcvTablasDinamicas
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            generarTabla();
        }

        public static void generarTabla()
        {

            int cError = 0;

            Boolean error;
            Application xlApp = null;
            do
            {
                error = false;
                try
                {
                    xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    error = true;
                    cError++;
                }
            } while (error && cError < 10);
            Workbook xlWorkbook;
            String excelpath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "EMCV.xlsx";




            xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excelpath);
            Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];




//De aquí en adelante empiezan los fallos, no sé como solucionarlos o que alternativas podría usar
            //ESTA REGION NO FUNCIONA. No vale ni pa cagar, pero en los ejemplos de codeproject pone que si//
            #region "Aquí creamos la tabla dinámica"
            //Cantidad de datos en este caso son 100, normalmente esto se recibe de una Lista y hago Lista.Count
            int cantidadDeDatos = 100;
            Range pivotData = xlWorksheet.Range["N35:R" + Convert.ToString(500 + cantidadDeDatos + 1)];//Cantidad de datos +1 ya que también quiero incluir el rango de los alias. 

            //Ya a partir de aquí no sé exactamente lo que pasa, entendía que pivotDestination era donde iría la tabla.
            Range pivotDestination = xlWorksheet.Range["A1:A1", Type.Missing]; 

            PivotCache oPivotCache = (PivotCache)xlWorkbook.PivotCaches().Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, pivotData);
            PivotCaches pch = xlWorkbook.PivotCaches();
            pch.Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, pivotData).CreatePivotTable(xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1], "Franjas horarias", Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            PivotTable pvt = xlWorksheet.PivotTables("Franjas horarias") as PivotTable;

            //DEFINIR 'FILTRO DE INFORME'
            PivotField fld = ((PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("Platform"));
            fld.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField;
            fld.set_Subtotals(1, false);

            //DEFINIR FILTROS DE FILA
            fld = ((PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("Mes"));
            fld.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
            fld.set_Subtotals(1, false);

            //DEFINIR FILTROS DE FILA
            fld = ((PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("Dia"));
            fld.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
            fld.set_Subtotals(1, false);

            fld = ((PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("Count"));
            fld.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
            //Se supone que este método le funciona a todo dios, todo el mundo lo usa en internet pero a mi me dice
            //'_Worksheet.PivotTables(object)' es un método, que no es válida en el contexto indicado.

            #endregion



            xlWorkbook.Save();
            xlWorkbook.Close();
            xlApp.Quit();

        }




    }
}
```

Este es el proceso que se hace normalmente:

1- Seleccionar los datos en Excel

2- darle a tabla dinámica

3- Posicionar los nombres de columnas en cada lugar

[image: Menú de excel]

Después hacemos esto de manera de que se nos crea la tabla dinámica.

[image: Creación de tabla dinámica]

He estado buscando cosas parecidas en internet pero no he encontrado ningún ejemplo que me sirva, o que pueda utilizar,o algo.

¿Alguna forma de adaptar los datos a el formato?

> Al final lo que me tiene que quedar es algo de este estilo

[image: Ejemplo de formato]

**AÑADO AQUÍ DATOS QUE SE PUEDEN PASAR A EXCEL POR SI ALGUIEN QUIERE PROBAR EL PROGRAMA.**

```
+-----+--------+-----+-----+------+-------+
|     |   A    |  B  |  C  |  D   |   E   |
+-----+--------+-----+-----+------+-------+
|   1 | Alias  | Mes | Dia | Hora | Count |
|   2 | Alias1 | 1   | 2   | 8    | 6     |
|   3 | Alias2 | 3   | 2   | 9    | 28    |
|   4 | Alias1 | 1   | 2   | 10   | 36    |
|   5 | Alias2 | 1   | 2   | 11   | 41    |
|   6 | Alias2 | 1   | 2   | 12   | 31    |
|   7 | Alias1 | 2   | 2   | 13   | 23    |
|   8 | Alias1 | 2   | 2   | 14   | 10    |
|   9 | Alias2 | 2   | 2   | 15   | 12    |
|  10 | Alias2 | 2   | 2   | 16   | 24    |
|  11 | Alias1 | 1   | 2   | 17   | 11    |
|  12 | Alias2 | 1   | 2   | 18   | 17    |
|  13 | Alias2 | 1   | 2   | 19   | 4     |
|  14 | Alias1 | 1   | 2   | 20   | 3     |
|  15 | Alias2 | 1   | 2   | 21   | 1     |
|  16 | Alias1 | 2   | 3   | 8    | 7     |
|  17 | Alias1 | 2   | 3   | 9    | 23    |
|  18 | Alias2 | 2   | 3   | 10   | 44    |
|  19 | Alias1 | 2   | 3   | 11   | 42    |
|  20 | Alias2 | 1   | 3   | 12   | 41    |
|  21 | Alias1 | 1   | 3   | 13   | 26    |
|  22 | Alias2 | 1   | 3   | 14   | 6     |
|  23 | Alias1 | 1   | 3   | 15   | 4     |
|  24 | Alias1 | 1   | 3   | 16   | 10    |
|  25 | Alias1 | 3   | 3   | 17   | 22    |
|  26 | Alias1 | 1   | 3   | 18   | 8     |
|  27 | Alias2 | 3   | 3   | 19   | 5     |
|  28 | Alias1 | 1   | 3   | 20   | 7     |
|  29 | Alias2 | 1   | 3   | 21   | 2     |
|  30 | Alias1 | 1   | 4   | 8    | 6     |
|  31 | Alias2 | 1   | 4   | 9    | 24    |
|  32 | Alias1 | 1   | 4   | 10   | 29    |
|  33 | Alias2 | 2   | 4   | 11   | 26    |
|  34 | Alias2 | 2   | 4   | 12   | 18    |
|  35 | Alias1 | 2   | 4   | 13   | 16    |
|  36 | Alias1 | 2   | 4   | 14   | 10    |
|  37 | Alias1 | 2   | 4   | 15   | 12    |
|  38 | Alias1 | 2   | 4   | 16   | 13    |
|  39 | Alias2 | 1   | 4   | 17   | 20    |
|  40 | Alias1 | 1   | 4   | 18   | 13    |
|  41 | Alias2 | 1   | 4   | 19   | 6     |
|  42 | Alias2 | 1   | 4   | 20   | 4     |
|  43 | Alias1 | 1   | 4   | 21   | 2     |
|  44 | Alias2 | 1   | 5   | 8    | 7     |
|  45 | Alias1 | 1   | 5   | 9    | 21    |
|  46 | Alias1 | 3   | 5   | 10   | 34    |
|  47 | Alias1 | 3   | 5   | 11   | 37    |
|  48 | Alias2 | 3   | 5   | 12   | 15    |
|  49 | Alias1 | 3   | 5   | 13   | 17    |
|  50 | Alias2 | 3   | 5   | 14   | 15    |
|  51 | Alias2 | 1   | 5   | 15   | 9     |
|  52 | Alias2 | 1   | 5   | 16   | 9     |
|  53 | Alias1 | 1   | 5   | 17   | 9     |
|  54 | Alias2 | 1   | 5   | 18   | 3     |
|  55 | Alias1 | 1   | 5   | 19   | 2     |
|  56 | Alias1 | 1   | 5   | 20   | 3     |
|  57 | Alias1 | 1   | 5   | 21   | 2     |
|  58 | Alias1 | 2   | 6   | 14   | 1     |
|  59 | Alias2 | 3   | 8   | 8    | 29    |
|  60 | Alias2 | 3   | 8   | 9    | 42    |
|  61 | Alias2 | 3   | 8   | 10   | 51    |
|  62 | Alias2 | 2   | 8   | 11   | 48    |
|  63 | Alias2 | 2   | 8   | 12   | 47    |
|  64 | Alias1 | 2   | 8   | 13   | 47    |
|  65 | Alias1 | 2   | 8   | 14   | 16    |
|  66 | Alias2 | 1   | 8   | 15   | 8     |
|  67 | Alias1 | 1   | 8   | 16   | 23    |
|  68 | Alias1 | 1   | 8   | 17   | 26    |
|  69 | Alias1 | 1   | 8   | 18   | 23    |
|  70 | Alias1 | 2   | 8   | 19   | 11    |
|  71 | Alias2 | 2   | 8   | 20   | 4     |
|  72 | Alias1 | 2   | 8   | 21   | 1     |
|  73 | Alias1 | 2   | 9   | 8    | 15    |
|  74 | Alias2 | 3   | 9   | 9    | 33    |
|  75 | Alias1 | 3   | 9   | 10   | 48    |
|  76 | Alias1 | 3   | 9   | 11   | 43    |
|  77 | Alias2 | 2   | 9   | 12   | 48    |
|  78 | Alias1 | 3   | 9   | 13   | 29    |
|  79 | Alias1 | 1   | 9   | 14   | 14    |
|  80 | Alias1 | 1   | 9   | 15   | 8     |
|  81 | Alias1 | 1   | 9   | 16   | 24    |
|  82 | Alias2 | 1   | 9   | 17   | 21    |
|  83 | Alias1 | 3   | 9   | 18   | 17    |
|  84 | Alias1 | 2   | 9   | 19   | 9     |
|  85 | Alias1 | 1   | 9   | 20   | 6     |
|  86 | Alias1 | 2   | 9   | 21   | 2     |
|  87 | Alias2 | 2   | 10  | 8    | 10    |
|  88 | Alias2 | 2   | 10  | 9    | 40    |
|  89 | Alias2 | 1   | 10  | 10   | 61    |
|  90 | Alias1 | 2   | 10  | 11   | 35    |
|  91 | Alias1 | 3   | 10  | 12   | 27    |
|  92 | Alias2 | 1   | 10  | 13   | 25    |
|  93 | Alias2 | 2   | 10  | 14   | 14    |
|  94 | Alias1 | 1   | 10  | 15   | 28    |
|  95 | Alias1 | 1   | 10  | 16   | 19    |
|  96 | Alias2 | 3   | 10  | 17   | 26    |
|  97 | Alias1 | 3   | 10  | 18   | 12    |
|  98 | Alias2 | 3   | 10  | 19   | 6     |
|  99 | Alias1 | 3   | 10  | 20   | 1     |
| 100 | Alias1 | 3   | 10  | 21   | 5     |
+-----+--------+-----+-----+------+-------+
```

Comment: Si el objetivo es llevar datos de SQL a Excel, ¿para qué C#? ¿Estás procesando, analizando o modificando algo en tu programa? Porque de lo contrario, te diría que conectes Excel directamente a la tabla en tu base de datos... O mejor dicho, ¿cuál es la pregunta? porque ya sabés crear tablas dinámicas, ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: El problema es que manualmente si que creamos tablas dinámicas, pero esta hoja de cálculo coge datos de varios ``datasources`` , lo que se pretende es que la persona que rellena todo esto no pierda media hora todos los días en rellenarlo. 
El proceso en sí, incluye varios paso más a parte de la inserción de datos. Lo último que me queda por automatizar es esa parte. Por eso lo necesito. Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: Si te entendí bien, entonces con más razón.. No hay motivo para pasarlo por C#. Se conecta desde Excel para que tome la tabla de SQL y rellene una tabla X... El origen de datos de tu tabla dinámica es esa Tabla X... Sólo hay que actualizar todos los datos del Excel para que conecte a la base y actualice la tabla, y luego se actualice la tabla dinámica... todo automático con 1 solo click en Excel

Comment: Pero no podría hacer una especie de Count .... para que me muestre todos los datos que cumplan X condiciones, o si? no sé, valoraré esa opción, pero lo ideal sería tenerlo todo hecho en un desarrollo.

Comment: @Podrías hacerlo en SQL o en la tabla dinámica de Excel, donde prefieras

Comment: La idea era que mediante C# darle formato a los datos recibidos a través de una consulta.

Comment: Me parece que esto se debe de solucionar armando un datatable(O datagrid) con toda la informacion que ocupas, luego exportandola. Porque al final solo son totales los que tienes. Habría que ver como armas esas tablas dinamicas con la informacion de la consulta. No lo veo dificil, tienes que procesar un ejemplo de como operas la data de la consulta en la tabla dinamica. Pero la forma que elegiria es conectar Excel a SQL

Comment: hola @Aritzbn porque en vez de llenar datatables, haces una consulta pivot desde sql directamente y el resultado lo llevas a el excell?
ejemplos de tablas pivot https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/be0f5b88-282b-4856-8d82-99b93ecf36a5/crear-pivot-dinamico?forum=sqlserveres

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/communitydocs/servidores/sql-server/pivot-dinamico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voy a dejar una posible solución aquí, pese a no ser la más correcta o ideal, es la que me ha funcionado después de mucho tiempo.

De una forma muy resumida esto es lo que he hecho:

```
1- Crear hoja auxiliar
2- Insertar datos que se utilizarán en la tabla, extraídos de SQL, en hoja auxiliar
3- Grabar macro con excel, teniendo en cuenta la hoja auxiliar
4- Pasar el código de la macro generada por excel a Documento de texto
5- Ejecutarla usando las librerías de interop
6- Reestructurar el excel como quiero (nombres de hojas etc.)
```

Para generar la macro en excel:

```
Vista>Macros>Grabar Macro
```

Ejecutarla desde c#

```
        Boolean error;
        int cError = 0;
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = null;

        do
        {
            error = false;
            try
            {
                xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Ruta del archivo+archivo.xls");
                xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                error = true;
                cError++;
            }
        } while (error && cError < 10);

        Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets["Hoja1"];
        Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.VBComponent oModule;

        oModule = xlWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);

        oModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(File.ReadAllText(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Macro.txt"));

        xlWorkbook.Application.Run("Nombre de la funcion");
```

De esta forma puedes ejecutar un módulo VBA en excel, donde en teoría has programado o se ha programado la generación de tabla dinámicas.

> Algo a tener en cuenta es que, al crear las tablas dinámicas, no puedes hacer el que se creen en Hoja1 celda A1, da un error muy genérico, tanto haciéndolo desde el propio excel como al ejecutarlo como módulo. La forma que permite excel hacerlo es crearlo en una nueva hoja siempre, de esta forma no da error.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar algo así, he probado este código en Visual C# y funciona bien. En el paso 2 yo he prefijado una lista de 8 objetos, pero tú lo puedes reemplazar por tu lista leída desde la base de datos:

```
            //1.
            var AppExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook LibroExcel;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet HojaExcel;

            /*
             TITULOS DE LA LISTA DE MEDICIONES
             */
            LibroExcel = AppExcel.Workbooks.Add();
            HojaExcel = LibroExcel.Worksheets.Add();


            //2.
            int nroColumnas = 3;
            int nroFilas = 8;
            var data = new object[nroFilas, nroColumnas];
            int fila = 100;

            HojaExcel.Rows.Item[1].Font.Bold = 1;
            HojaExcel.Rows.Item[1].Font.size = 12;

            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 31] = "PAIS";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 32] = "CIUDAD";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 33] = "VENTAS";
            fila++;

            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 31] = "PERU";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 32] = "LIMA";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 33] = 2015;
            fila++;
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 31] = "PERU";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 32] = "TRUJILLO";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 33] = 4524;
            fila++;
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 31] = "COLOMBIA";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 32] = "CALI";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 33] = 452782;
            fila++;
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 31] = "COLOMBIA";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 32] = "BOGOTA";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 33] = 42577;
            fila++;
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 31] = "BOLIVIA";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 32] = "LA PAZ";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 33] = 4747;
            fila++;
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 31] = "BRAZIL";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 32] = "SAO APULO";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 33] = 4524;
            fila++;
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 31] = "ECUADOR";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 32] = "QUITO";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 33] = 27578;
            fila++;
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 31] = "ECUADOR";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 32] = "CUENCA";
            HojaExcel.Cells[fila, 33] = 57789;
            fila++;

            Excel.Range c1 = (Excel.Range)HojaExcel.Cells[100, 31]; //1, 111
            Excel.Range c2 = (Excel.Range)HojaExcel.Cells[nroFilas + 100, 31 + nroColumnas - 1];
            Excel.Range range = HojaExcel.get_Range(c1, c2);
            //range.Value = data;


            ////3.
            Excel.Range oRange = range; // HojaExcel.UsedRange;
            Excel.PivotCache oPivotCache = (Excel.PivotCache)LibroExcel.PivotCaches().Add(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, oRange);  // Set the Source data range from First sheet
            //Excel.Range oRange2 = HojaExcel.Cells[1, 1];
            Excel.PivotCaches pch = LibroExcel.PivotCaches();
            pch.Add(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, oRange).CreatePivotTable(HojaExcel.Cells[1, 1], "PivTbl_1", Type.Missing, Type.Missing);// Create Pivot table
            Excel.PivotTable pvt = HojaExcel.PivotTables("PivTbl_1") as Excel.PivotTable;

            pvt.ShowDrillIndicators = false;  // Used to remove the Expand/ Collapse Button from each cell

            Excel.PivotField fld = ((Excel.PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("PAIS")); // Create a Pivot Field in Pivot table
            fld.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField;
            fld.set_Subtotals(1, false);

            fld = ((Excel.PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("CIUDAD"));
            fld.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
            fld.set_Subtotals(1, false);

            fld = ((Excel.PivotField)pvt.PivotFields("VENTAS"));
            fld.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;

            //HojaExcel.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit();  // Used to Autoset the column width according to data 
            pvt.ColumnGrand = false;  // Used to hide Grand total for columns
            pvt.RowGrand = false; // Used to hide Grand total for Rows

            HojaExcel.Columns.AutoFit();
            //HojaExcel.Rows.AutoFit();
            AppExcel.Application.Visible = true;
            HojaExcel = null;
            LibroExcel = null;
            AppExcel = null;
```

Comment: No creo que esto me vaya a servir para resolver el problema que tengo, más que nada por que necesito que salga con el mismo formato que el creador de hojas dinámicas de excel, y esto solo me colocaría la información.

Comment: Te respondo tras unos días y haber intentado aplicar lo que me dijiste de alguna forma. Me da una excepción, no sé si sabrás el por qué. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'  , sale cuando hago esto ``pch.Add(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, pivotData).CreatePivotTable(xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1], "Franjas horarias", Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            ``